# Setting tabBarAppearance makes it so UITabBarItem doesn't respect `imageInsets`

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, uitabbar

When I set the UITabBar's appearance, it makes it so the UITabBarItem's `imageInsets` and `titlePositionAdjustment` aren't respected anymore on iOS 15. Removing the line `[UITabBar appearance].standardAppearance = tabBarAppearance;` makes it so the image and label lineup but the background color can't be set. Has anyone run into something like this and solved it?

Code:

```
UITabBarAppearance *tabBarAppearance = [[UITabBarAppearance alloc] init];
[tabBarAppearance configureWithOpaqueBackground];
[UITabBar appearance].standardAppearance = tabBarAppearance;
[UITabBar appearance].scrollEdgeAppearance = tabBarAppearance;

static let tabBarImageInsets: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 4.0, left: 0, bottom: -4.0, right: 0)
static let titlePositionAdjustmentValue: UIOffset = UIOffset(horizontal: 0.0, vertical: -8.0)
tabBarItem.imageInsets = tabBarImageInsets
tabBarItem.titlePositionAdjustment = titlePositionAdjustmentValue
```

Images:

[Tab Bar with appearance and misaligned label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9hUz.png)

[Tab Bar without appearance, properly aligned label and image, and no background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xftIm.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this after actually reading the Apple docs:

```
if (@available(iOS 15.0, *)) {
        UINavigationBarAppearance *navBarAppearance = [[UINavigationBarAppearance alloc] init];
        [navBarAppearance configureWithOpaqueBackground];
        [UINavigationBar appearance].standardAppearance = navBarAppearance;
        [UINavigationBar appearance].compactAppearance = navBarAppearance;
        [UINavigationBar appearance].scrollEdgeAppearance = navBarAppearance;

        UITabBarAppearance *tabBarAppearance = [[UITabBarAppearance alloc] init];
        [tabBarAppearance configureWithOpaqueBackground];
        [UITabBar appearance].standardAppearance = tabBarAppearance;
        [UITabBar appearance].scrollEdgeAppearance = tabBarAppearance;

        UITabBarItemAppearance *tabBarItemAppearance = [[UITabBarItemAppearance alloc] init];

        tabBarItemAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = [[RRUIDesignToken.font nav] makeTextAttributes];
        if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
            tabBarItemAppearance.normal.titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffsetMake(0.0, -[RRUIDesignToken.size paddingXsmall]);
        } else {
            tabBarItemAppearance.normal.titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffsetMake(0.0, -[RRUIDesignToken.size paddingXxsmall]);
        }

        tabBarAppearance.stackedLayoutAppearance = tabBarItemAppearance;
        tabBarAppearance.compactInlineLayoutAppearance = tabBarItemAppearance;
        tabBarAppearance.inlineLayoutAppearance = tabBarItemAppearance;
    }
```